# XML RPC server (PHP, Drupal) incompatibility with client (Java) on long integers

Tags: java, php, drupal, type-conversion, xml-rpc

I am writing a Java application which communicates with a Drupal-based backed using XML RPC.

One of the methods expects a dictionary of objects, which is fine since it is automatically converted to `<struct>`. However, the [client library](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc) converts `Map<String, Object>` in the way that any integers get converted to longs. To [support long integers](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/types.html) in the XMLRPC call, one has to enable [vendor extensions](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/extensions.html). These extensions, however, are not supported by the server.

As much as I can see, there is nothing in PHP that would enable support for tags like `<ex:i8>`. Interestingly, the [supposedly official site for XMLRPC extensions](http://ontosys.com/xml-rpc/extensions.php) does not define the ones [detailed here](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/types.html).

Is there any way to make a correct call here short of looping through all members of the `Map<String, Object>` and manually converting all longs to integers?

Comment: Sorry to writing here - there is just no way to send private messages.
I am developing similar application: Java application which communicates with a Drupal-based backed using XML RPC and I have few questions. If you wish to chat, catch me @ skype or gtalk or msn or gmail - my nick is moisei everythere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing this code which converts all `Long` instances to `Integer` in a `Map`, `HashMap` or a `JSONObject`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Object fixLongs(Object p)
{
    String t = p.getClass().getName();
    if (t == "java.util.Map" || t == "java.util.HashMap" || t == "org.json.simple.JSONObject")
    {
        HashMap<Object, Object> n = new HashMap<Object, Object>(((HashMap<Object, Object>) p).size());
        Iterator<Entry<Object, Object>> it = ((HashMap<Object, Object>) p).entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            Entry<Object, Object> e = it.next();
            n.put(this.fixLongs(e.getKey()), this.fixLongs(e.getValue()));
        }
        return n;
    }
    else if (t == "java.lang.Long")
    {
        return new Integer(((Long) p).intValue());
    }
    else
    {
        return p;
    }
}
```